# PostgreSQL: How to list all stored functions that access specific table

Tags: postgresql, information-schema

**Introduction:**

PostgreSQL database with several hundred of stored functions, including obsolete, not used etc.

**Problem**

I need to find out all the stored functions that have any relationship to the table X - as I want to change the table structure. Some of them might be not used, so I can't do that just by looking through the code.

The solution I have ATM is running psql's `\df+` and grepping output, but I'd prefer more database-like solution, i.e. by using information schema. This will definitely be a repetitive task and I'd like to have it nice and clean.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The body of a function is just stored as *string*. There is no list of referenced objects. (That's different from views, for instance, where actual links to referenced tables are saved.)

This query for **Postgres 10 or older** uses the [system catalog information function `pg_get_functiondef()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) to reconstruct the `CREATE FUNCTION` script for relevant functions and searches for the table name with a case-insensitive regular expression:

```
SELECT n.nspname AS schema_name
     , p.proname AS function_name
     , pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) AS args
     , pg_get_functiondef(p.oid) AS func_def
FROM   pg_proc p
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE  NOT p.proisagg
AND    n.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
AND    n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
AND    pg_get_functiondef(p.oid) ~* '\mbig\M';
```

It should do the job, but it's obviously not bullet-proof. It can fail for dynamic SQL where the table name is generated dynamically and it can return any number of false positives - especially if the table name is a common word.

Aggregate functions and all functions from system schemas are excluded.

[`\m` and `\M`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE) mark the beginning and end of a word in the regular expression.

The system catalog `pg_proc` changed in Postgres 11. `proisagg` was replaced by `prokind`, true stored procedures were added. You need to adapt. Related:

- [How to drop all of my functions in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122742/how-to-drop-all-of-my-functions-in-postgresql/122777#122777)

Comment: Yep... it's not totally robust, in the sense that it won't find `EXECUTE` expressions like `'mm_'||name_parameter`, and it won't cope correctly with quoted names like `"my""table""` or with case-folding, but it'll do most of what most people will want.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Yeah, dynamic queries with `EXECUTE` are almost impossible to cover. But case-folding can be covered with `~*` instead of `~` - or any other case-insensitive pattern-matching.

Comment: So long as the operator isn't crazy enough to actually create tables named `"MyTable"` and `MyTable`, at least... and honestly, that's a "well, that might be allowed but it isn't smart" move.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually don't use dynamic table name construction anywhere and all table names are lowercase.

Answer (score 6):

This query is pretty easy to use:

```
SELECT proname, proargnames, prosrc FROM pg_proc WHERE prosrc ILIKE '%Text to search%';
```