# How to drop all of my functions in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, functions, dynamic-sql

Right now I have to use query to get the command in text file.
Then remove double quote from them. And finally, run that file in psql shell.

How can drop all of my functions in PostgreSQL **in a single step**?

Comment: Don't use raw `||`. Use `quote_ident` or the `format` function with the `%I` format-specifier. That way identifier quoting is handled properly. Use a `DO` block to `EXECUTE` the queries you generate to avoid doing it in multiple steps. See [tag:dynamic-sql], [tag:postgresql]

Comment: I am reading on your given links. Thank you.

Comment: Removed the lengthy steps as they're relatively irrelevant. Also edited the title, they're not "your" functions unless you're testing for ownership. They're just functions in a schema that you can drop.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To drop all functions (including aggregates) in a given schema (**be careful with this!**):

#### Postgres 11 or later

- [Procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createprocedure.html) have been added.
- The system catalog `pg_proc` slightly changed: `prokind` replaces `proisagg` and `proiswindow` - and also tags *functions* and the new *procedures*

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _sql text;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _sql
          string_agg(format('DROP %s %s;'
                          , CASE prokind
                              WHEN 'f' THEN 'FUNCTION'
                              WHEN 'a' THEN 'AGGREGATE'
                              WHEN 'p' THEN 'PROCEDURE'
                              WHEN 'w' THEN 'FUNCTION'  -- window function (rarely applicable)
                              -- ELSE NULL              -- not possible in pg 11
                            END
                          , oid::regprocedure)
                   , E'\n')
   FROM   pg_proc
   WHERE  pronamespace = 'public'::regnamespace  -- schema name here!
   -- AND    prokind = ANY ('{f,a,p,w}')         -- optionally filter kinds
   ;

   IF _sql IS NOT NULL THEN
      RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;  -- debug / check first
      -- EXECUTE _sql;         -- uncomment payload once you are sure
   ELSE 
      RAISE NOTICE 'No fuctions found in schema %', quote_ident(_schema);
   END IF;
END
$do$;
```

The schema name is case sensitive in this context.
The executing role needs to have the necessary privileges of course.

You might add `CASCADE` [like demonstrated by mehmet](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/217320/3684) but that will also drop depending objects, recursively - not just functions. Makes it even more dangerous. You better know exactly what you are doing.

Related, with more explanation:

- [How to drop function from all schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29414242/939860)
- [DROP FUNCTION without knowing the number/type of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7623246/939860)

#### Postgres 10 or older

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _sql text;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _sql
          string_agg(format('DROP %s %s;'
                          , CASE WHEN proisagg THEN 'AGGREGATE' ELSE 'FUNCTION' END
                          , oid::regprocedure)
                   , E'\n')
   FROM   pg_proc
   WHERE  pronamespace = 'public'::regnamespace;  -- schema name here!

   IF _sql IS NOT NULL THEN
      RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;  -- debug / check first
      -- EXECUTE _sql;         -- uncomment payload once you are sure
   ELSE 
      RAISE NOTICE 'No fuctions found in schema %', quote_ident(_schema);
   END IF;
END
$do$;
```

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter do you a similar method to drop all custom types? I could post a question, if you haven't answered this, here or at SO.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: A similar procedure should get it done. But you need to define "custom type". Only from a given schema? Row types of user tables would qualify as "custom types", too, but cannot be dropped while the table depends on it. I suggest you start a new question with defining info.

Answer (score 5):

I had to touch-up Erwin's answer above for several cases:

1) If you had an aggregate function in the schema that triggered and error.
2) If you wanted to drop functions in two schemas and the function that deletes is in the first, it got deleted too. 
3) If functions depended on each other. Use cascade to force-drop.

Here it is:

```
create or replace function data.delete_all_functions(schema_in text)
    returns void as
$$
declare
    qry text;

begin
    select into qry string_agg(
       format(
          case when proname = 'delete_all_functions' then '-- %s;' -- don't delete self
               when proisagg then 'drop aggregate if exists %s cascade;'
               else 'drop function if exists %s cascade;'
             end,
          oid :: regprocedure
          ),
       E'\n'
        )
    from pg_proc
    where pronamespace = schema_in :: regnamespace;

    if qry is not null then
        execute qry;
        raise notice 'deleted all functions in schema: %', schema_in;
    else
        raise notice 'no functions to delete in schema: %', schema_in;
    end if;
end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Oh, just saw your added answer. Yes, your additions all make sense.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter sorry I was little too impatient :)

Comment: `pg_proc.proisagg` is no longer with us with pg version 11

Answer (score 1):

I took the correct answer above and made it into a function that generated the script passing in the schema name and a search pattern as params.  I keep a few of these in my db during design phase but either lock them down or remove them from production.

```
CREATE FUNCTION extfunc.systool_generatescript_functiondelete(
    schemaname character varying,
    searchpattern character varying)
    RETURNS character varying
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    
AS $BODY$
Declare
_sql text;
BEGIN

    SELECT INTO _sql
        string_agg(format('DROP %s %s;'
                          , CASE prokind
                              WHEN 'f' THEN 'FUNCTION'
                              WHEN 'a' THEN 'AGGREGATE'
                              WHEN 'p' THEN 'PROCEDURE'
                              WHEN 'w' THEN 'FUNCTION'  -- window function (rarely applicable)
                              -- ELSE NULL              -- not possible in pg 11
                             END
                          , oid::regprocedure)
                   , E'\n')
    FROM   pg_proc
    WHERE  pronamespace = schemaname::regnamespace   -- schema name here!
    -- AND    prokind = ANY ('{f,a,p,w}')         -- optionally filter kinds
    AND oid::regprocedure::varchar LIKE ('%' || searchpattern || '%');

    RETURN _sql;
    
END;
$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 0):

The one-step variants are hard to understand, so here are simple steps on HeidiSQL, but I hope you can do it on any DB viewer.
Make a table that generates queries to delete functions

```
SELECT 'DROP FUNCTION "' || p.proname || '";'
FROM 
    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN 
    pg_catalog.pg_proc p ON 
    p.pronamespace = n.oid
WHERE 
    p.prokind = 'f'
AND
    n.nspname = 'public';
```

or

```
SELECT 
    'DROP FUNCTION "' || ROUTINE_NAME || '";'
FROM 
    information_schema.routines
WHERE 
    routine_type = 'FUNCTION'
AND
    routine_schema = 'public';
```

So here you see some rows:

```
DROP FUNCTION "a_i_aspnetuserclaims_f";
DROP FUNCTION "a_d_aspnetroleclaims_f";
DROP FUNCTION "a_d_aspnetuserclaims_f";
DROP FUNCTION "a_d_channels_f";
DROP FUNCTION "a_d_aspnetuserlogins_f";
```

Select all rows, then click "Export" as text on your buffer. So you could insert it to execute:
[image]

Comment: I liked this approx : ``` SELECT 'DROP FUNCTION ' || p.proname || '(' || oidvectortypes(proargtypes) ||');'
FROM     pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN     pg_catalog.pg_proc p ON   p.pronamespace = n.oid
WHERE    p.prokind = 'f' AND    n.nspname = 'public'; ``` works even better