# Posgresql: delete all custom defined tables, functions, procedures and enums on current database

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a procedure to delete all custom defined elements in the current database I'm operating with. That includes:

- tables
- procedures
- functions
- enums

I don't want to drop schema and recreate it: the idea is just to delete these elements.

This is an attempt I did taking code from [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122742/how-to-drop-all-of-my-functions-in-postgresql) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327312/how-can-i-drop-all-the-tables-in-a-postgresql-database).

```sql
drop procedure if exists reset_db;

create procedure reset_db() language plpgsql AS $$

begin
  -- Drop all functions and procedures
  declare _sql text;
  begin
    select into _sql
            string_agg(format('DROP %s %s;'
                            , case prokind
                                when 'f' then 'FUNCTION'
                                when 'p' then 'PROCEDURE'
                              end
                            , oid::regprocedure)
                    , E'\n')
    from   pg_proc
    where  pronamespace = current_schema()::regnamespace
    ;

    if _sql is not null then
        raise notice '%', _sql;  -- debug / check first
        execute _sql;         -- uncomment payload once you are sure
    else
        raise notice 'No fuctions found in schema %', quote_ident(_schema);
    end if;
  end;

  -- Drop custom types. Don't know how to iterate here to automate it.
  drop type LevelEnum cascade;
  drop type StatusEnum cascade;

  -- Drop all tables
  declare
    r record;
  begin
    for r in (select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname = current_schema()) loop
        execute 'drop table if exists ' || quote_ident(r.tablename) || ' cascade';
    end loop;
  end;

end;
$$;
```

Currently this seems to delete other functions apart of the ones I defined for my current DB.
Also I don't know how to loop through the custom defined types as the enums to delete them.

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: Not sure what exactly identifies "custom defined elements" for you, but are you looking for [`DROP SCHEMA`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-dropschema.html)?

Comment: As I said I don't want to drop the schema, just delete the mentioned elements.

Comment: And why, if I may ask, you don't want to drop the schema, if you drop everything in it?

Comment: AFAIK I'm not dropping everything.

Comment: What "other" functions is it dropping? Do you mean it drops functions in schemas other than `current_schema`? Did you try to use fully qualified names in your generated statements?

Answer (score 0):

The only good way to do that is to have all the objects you want to get rid of be owned by a certain role. Then you can run

```
DROP OWNED BY owning_role;
```